# CKEDITOR EqnEditor(Math plugin) not working on multiple instances on same page

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor (anuglar-ckeditor) and added a Eqneditor plugin for write mathematical expression. It is working fine with single instance of ckeditor on one page. But if i add multiple instance of ckeditor on same page, then eqneditor's hover not working.

In that case, if i have 2 instance on single page, and i open eqnEditor for first instance it is working, but when i will go to second instance editor's eqnEditor, its hover icon not showing.

Same thing is happening when i do reverse it. If i open second instance first then eqnEditor work fine for second instance, not for first.
I found only solution [here](http://www.codecogs.com/pages/forums/pagegen.php?id=2833) but its not working for me. I have same problem like this link.

Here is plugin in config.js file :-

```
config.extraPlugins = 'eqneditor',
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this topic is still open to discussion, but I felt at the same problem this week, and I've developed a solution.

https://github.com/ygorlazaro/eqneditorfix

It's just a .JS file you need to add at your project, and I'll fix this error.

This code removes and adds back from/to the DOM the EqnEditor. At this case, if the EqnEditor is binded to a event at another CKEditor, I give it a 'reload'. This is working without any need to reload the CKEditor itself (my first approach here).

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on what exactly your repo does?  An answer should be able to exist without relying on external sources which at this time this answer doesn't.

Comment: @YgorLazaro Thanks for your reply and solution. I have tried this but not working still :(

Comment: Strange. It worked at my project, even it been developed in AngularJS. Did you test it placing at the very bottom of the page?

Comment: @YgorLazaro i am also working with angularjs and trying adding into angular app. Yes i placed it at the end of page but not working. Working with latest version of ckeditor. thanks

Comment: any success for that